# How to optionally return value from map function

Tags: scala

`map` function on collections requires to return some value for each iteration. But I'm trying to find a way to return value not for each iteration, but only for initial values which matches some predicate .

What I want looks something like this:

```
(1 to 10).map { x =>
   val res: Option[Int] = service.getById(x)
   if (res.isDefined) Pair(x, res.get )// no else part

}
```

I think something like `.collect` function could do it, but seems with `collect` function I need to write many code in guards blocks (`case x if {...// too much code here}`)

Answer (score 8):

If you are returning an `Option` you can `flatMap` it and get only the values that are present (that is, are not `None`).

```
(1 to 10).flatMap { x =>
   val res: Option[Int] = service.getById(x)
   res.map{y => Pair(x, y) }
}
```

---

As you suggest, an alternative way to combine `map` and `filter` is to use `collect` and a partially applied function. Here is a simplified example:

```
(1 to 10).collect{ case x if x > 5 => x*2 }
res0: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(12, 14, 16, 18, 20)
```

Comment: since the OP sounded like his was searching for minimal code, I would rewrite as `(1 to 10).flatMap(x => service.getById(x).map(Pair(x, _)))`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the collect function [(see here)](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@collect[B](pf:PartialFunction[A,B]):List[B]) to do exactly what you want. Your example would then look like:

```
(1 to 10) map (x => (x, service.getById(x))) collect {  
  case (x, Some(res)) => Pair(x, res)
}
```

Comment: I like this solution as well. I am wondering if we can compare performance and see if there is any difference in using partially applied functions vs the flatmap solution  ...

Comment: I'm missing something here.  Where does `x` get retrieved from?  Hasn't it been lost by the time you're in the `collect()`?

Comment: Good point @jwvh. There is no x any more, we need to keep in the result of the first map (return a Tuple or something).

Answer (score 2):

Using a for comprehension, like this,

```
for ( x <- 1 to 10; res <- service.getById(x) ) yield Pair(x, res.get)
```

This yields pairs where `res` does not evaluate to `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the first element:

```
(1 to 10).flatMap { x =>
   val res: Option[Int] = service.getById(x)
   res.map{y => Pair(x, y) }
}.head
```